# Manual Release of Job fails in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, rabbitmq

I'm currently using Laravel's Queue to process a job. I need to release this job some point in time but it runs immediately even if I implemented release(). Is this a bug of laravel or did I miss something?

```
public function handle()
{
     $this->release(120);

     var_dump('Hello World!!');  ---> This was displayed right after I called the Job

}
```

Also, `QUEUE_DRIVER` is set to RabbitMQ

Answer (score 0):

I don't think release is what you want. Release is that is will be put back into the queue after 120 seconds of being worked at.

If you want it to be in the queue for at least 120 seconds you can used delayed dispatching. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#delayed-dispatching

For reference:

```
$job = (new MyJob())->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(2));
dispatch($job);
```